# R.id.image to string in android

Tags: android, image, filenames

In my project I'm trying to display several image files by manipulating the filename of one of the images programatically.

ie, I may have:
    filename.jpg, filename_top.jpg, filename_middle.jpg

I receive input of an drawable int and am trying to find the filename of the displayed image before manipulating this filename and trying to display the programatically generated filenames.. problem is that the manipulated filename does not display.
ie. there is something wrong with this:
    imageView2.setImageResource(getImageId(this, namebottom));

Any ideas how getImageId can be modified to make setImageResource work properly?

The code would look something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Bundle bun = getIntent().getExtras();
int imagenumber = bun.getInt("imagenumber");
String extension = bun.getString("extension");
// int become a val from 0 to 20 (array size)
setContentView(R.layout.clickeditem);

final int[] imgIds = new int[{
R.drawable.image0,R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,,,R.drawable.image20};

//The first image with id top in the layout is set ok:
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.top);
imageView1.setImageResource(imgIds [ imagenumber ] );
// problem here:
//try to get the name of this file: ie: filename.jpg
//       and then manipulate the filename:
String name = imageView1.getResources().getString(R.id.image0); 
//try to convert this to the filename_middle.jpg         
String namemiddle = name.replace(".jpg", "_middle.jpg");
imageViewt.setImageResource(getImageId(this, namemiddle)); 

//try to convert this to filename_bottom.jpg
String namebottom = name.replace(".jpg", "_bottom.jpg");
imageView2.setImageResource(getImageId(this, namebottom)); 
}

//where getImageId is defines as follows:
public static int getImageId(Context context, String imageName) 
{
return context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + imageName,
 null, context.getPackageName());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + imageName,
 null, context.getPackageName());
```

replace this by

```
return context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName,
 "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, it helped with my understanding of identifiers and tags. However, there was still a problem..

What was wrong with my above code was that I was passing the .jpg to the function. 

`int return_val = context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + imageName, null, context.getPackageName());`

works fine, but requires that the filename not be provided. (ie. imagename=filename_top filename_middle etc.. not filename_top.jpg etc..
Call as follows:

`imageViewm.setImageResource(getImageId(this, namem));`


Hopefully helpful to others.